# How fix GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, "(yb)" does not match expected type "(b)"?

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown

For roughly a week now I am sometimes getting "the bug". When "the bug" is present, I cannot start a terminal or thunderbird (some programs work; unsure why). When I try to shutdown the system I get `GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, "(yb)" does not match expected type "(b)"` and it doesn't.

When I first lock the screen and then press the shutdown button while the screen is locked, the system shuts down as expected. On reboot "the bug" is gone.

I am unsure what causes it, but have the feeling Thunderbird might be involved. I am unsure how to debug the issue to write a proper bug report if it really is a bug in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Clear the session cache.

open Settings -> Settings Manager -> Session and Startup -> Saved Sessions -> Clear saved sessions

Now you should be able to use the shutdown button again.

Comment: Lately the issue has been most rare. The next time it occurs, I will definitely try this method and once confirmed accept this as an answer.

Comment: I now encountered the problem again, but was unable to find Saved Sessions in `Clear saved session` also: Is this a one time fix or does it fix the entire problem? Because a onetime fix would not really help since I have a one time fix already as described in the question.

Comment: @natan after you clear it, make sure that you DON'T save your session, and logout first, then relogin, I got this error when I'm building my own XFCE, and... welp... after doing clear, log out then login, it will be okay. see https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9736

Comment: as I stated above I was unable to find `saved sessions>clear saved session` in Session and Startup as I have no session saved

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this by deleting the folder `/home/USERNAME/cache/sessions`

The problem emerged after Hibernating/Suspending a session. I always had similar issues with Ubuntu and Xubuntu